# How do I add my G Suite work email to my personal Gmail account?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace-for-business

I have two accounts: 1. `personal@gmail.com` and 2. `work@company.com`. Both accounts have 2-factor authentication enabled. I am a Super Admin for #2. I would like to add account #2 G Suite work email to account #1.

I cannot get past the SMTP step (Send mail through your SMTP server).

Everything I read is related to allowing "less secure apps". However, our current setting is set to "Allow users to manage their access to less secure apps"

First, I don't understand how my personal Gmail is a "less secure app" and second I don't know where to go from here.

Has anyone successfully done this?

Comment: The reason your personal email is a "less secure app" is because you cannot put in a 2-factor code to send SMTP messages.

Comment: Have you tried setting up an [app specific password](https://myaccount.google.com/apppasswords) for SMTP?

Comment: Really you should be using two factor auth and then assigning app passwords to things like gmail send through g-suite SMTP. This avoids downgrading security for less secure apps (which, I think, google is phasing out anyway)

Answer (score 8):

I detailed how to do this step-by-step in a medium post: https://medium.com/@csaba.apagyi/using-g-suite-gmail-from-your-personal-gmail-explained-step-by-step-6509187a710e

As for SMTP:

- Enable “Allow less secure apps to access account” option for users in G Suite admin
- Allow less secure apps in the G Suite account
- Ensure POP and SMTP are not disabled in G Suite admin
- Configure SMTP in the main Gmail account

You can find links to support pages for each step in the post linked above.

Comment: Great, this worked. You will also have to enable "Less secure app access" in the specific G Suite account

Comment: It's one of the steps above :) "Allow less secure apps in the G Suite account"

Comment: +1. Also for anyone wondering steps 1 and 2 are different and both required. Google also turns off step2 if you dont use it. quote: `Google will automatically turn this setting OFF if it’s not being used`

Comment: They are different, see: https://support.google.com/a/answer/6260879?hl=en and https://myaccount.google.com/u/3/lesssecureapps?pageId=none. Both were required when I wrote this answer.

Answer (score -1):

I need your help. I was facing same problem. and also Enable POP and IMAP and Allow less secure apps in the G Suite account from G Suite. At the user end also Enable POP and IMAP.
But still now problem not solved.

Thanks
Riton